# driver.save_screenshot создать папку с датой сегодня и записать туда скриншот с определенным названием

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Не могу понять как создать папку с датой сегоднящней, и сохранить туда скриншоты. А на следующий день создать другую папку с завтрашней датой и туда записать другие файлы и т.д.

> date_today= str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M"))
>   name_file=str(n)+'*'+('sait*')+str(link_now)+str(date_today)
>
> driver.save_screenshotg('\'+date_today+'\'+name_file)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time,random,re,datetime,os,errno
import traceback;#uotput error
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

saity=['http://lenta.ru/rss/news','http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/main.xml','http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/news.xml','http://rssportal.ru/feed/173256.xml','http://www.levada.ru/rss.xml','http://wsrss.bbc.co.uk/russian/index.xml','http://inosmi.ru/misc/export/xml/rss/translation.xml','http://news.google.ru/news?ned=ru_ru&topic=t&output=atom','http://112.ua/rss','http://thebestvideo.net/feed','http://feeds.feedburner.com/Astrobene']
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait_1=9
n=0


for i in reversed(range(len(saity))):
     try:
         link_now = saity.pop(random.randint(0, i))
         driver.get(link_now)
         time.sleep(wait_1)
         print(link_now)
         date_today= str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M"))
         name_file=str(n)+'_'+('sait_')+str(link_now)+str(date_today)
         name_file= name_file.replace('http://','').replace('.','').replace('/','_')
         name_file= name_file+'.png' #было бы замечательно в jpg

         print(name_file)
         driver.save_screenshot('\\'+date_today+'\\'+name_file)
         n+=1
     except Exception as exc:
         print(exc)
         traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Что-то у вас здесь все в кучу навалено. список называется `saity`, а данные вы берете из `generatory`. Переменная `n` не определена. Что касается сохранения файла - не плохо было бы сначала создать папку, в которую вы сохранять собрались (например `os.mkdir`). По поводу jpg - http://allselenium.info/taking-screenshot-using-python-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: 1) `strftime` и так возвращает строку, так что не нужно для него str вызывать 2) вместо `name_file=str(n)+'_'+('sait_')+str(link_now)+str(date_today)` пишите через `''.format` или `f-строки`, код станет проще, мир добрее и т.п. :) 3) когда в `driver.save_screenshot` передаете путь с новой папкой, тот создает папку и сохраняет туда скриншот или ругается на путь?

Answer (score 0):

> Не могу понять как создать папку с датой сегоднящней, и сохранить туда
> скриншоты. А на следующий день создать другую папку с завтрашней датой
> и туда записать другие файлы и т.д.

Смотрите [в таблицу формата](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), по ней выходит что у вас в строку попадут часы и минуты:

```
date_today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")
```

Соответственно, чтобы была исключительно текущая дата дня, нужно оставить только нужное:

```
date_today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d_%m_%Y")
```

Например, для сегодняшней даты, в `date_today` будет строка `'24_12_2018'`

---

**PS.**

Вместо

```
name_file=str(n)+'_'+('sait_')+str(link_now)+str(date_today)
```

попробуйте лучше:

```
name_file = '{}_sait_{}{}'.format(n, link_now, date_today)
```

или:

```
name_file = f'{n}_sait_{link_now}{date_today}'
```